# Link Email, Facebook and Twitter login to one Parse user

Tags: facebook, twitter, parse-platform

I want to let my users, after they signed up using their email, to attach their Facebook and/or Twitter account to their user.
Or, I want to let users that signed up using their Facebook account to attach their Twitter account.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser] permissions:nil];
```

and

```
[PFTwitterUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

Does the trick